# Tiled image viewer. With two images side by side that can be dynamically loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, seadragon

I'm trying to build a page in which two tiled images (for zooming in on) can be loaded and displayed side by side (then swapped out for different images at a click of a button). They both need to zoom in together but be separately tiled.

I've had a look at Seadragon but as far as I can see it is not possible to have two separately tiled images next to each other and zoom them together.

Can anyone propose a solution?

Thanks

Comment: I have nothing to show at the moment. I've just had a look at SeaDragon examples, it generates a view with a single tiled image. It doesn't seem to be possible to have two images side by side without generating the tiles for the two images together. Which wouldn't be dynamic enough for my needs. (need to grab each tiled image separately and put them side by side.)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.dimin.net/software/panojs/ it appears to have two images side by side when it starts in the maximum zoom out and as you zoom in it reveals more data from a set of larger tiled images.